# Submitting a form on casperjs that has no name

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs, selectors-api

This is the form that I'm going to submit

```
<form action="https://www.example.com/account/registration?execution=e2s1" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

In the sample code in the documentation of casperjs, submitting form is through this:

```
document.querySelector('form[name="f"]').submit();
```

How am I going to submit my form, if the name attribute was not specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use some CSS3 selector or XPath selector to do this. For example, when you open Chrome Developer Tools and right click on an element you have the option to *Copy CSS path* and *Copy XPath*. The CSS selector can be used with `querySelector`, but the XPath selector can only be used with [`evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.evaluate) inside of the page context.

Those copied selectors will be very rigid, since they only work by using the element tree. You could select the form with a [CSS attribute selector](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/):

```
document.querySelector('form[action*="account/registration?execution=e2s1"]').submit();
```

Here I use `*=` because you may not want to have the domain inside the selector and the protocol (https) may change later.

If you only have one form, you could just use

```
document.querySelector('form').submit();
```

or if you have only one form that has a `novalidate` attribute, you could use

```
document.querySelector('form[novalidate]').submit();
```